# How to get and pass the selected value to the tab controller in magento 1.9 admin?

Tags: php, magento-1.9

Now I am creating a module for magento admin page.Below is the screenshot
[image: block image]

What I want to do is, if I select "Template" in Dynamic block i want to get that option value and pass that value to the next "Text and images" tab(tab controller)

I don't know how to get that value and pass value to tab controller.
Here is some example code I want to pass the value in **URL**

```
 $this->addTab(
            'dynamicpages',
            array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('agile_dynamicproductpage')->__('Text and Images'),
                'url'   => $this->getUrl('*/*/dynamicpages', array('_current' => true, 'template' => 'How to get selected dropdown value here')),
                'class' => 'ajax'
            )
        );
```

**Below is the Controller action**

```
public function dynamicpagesAction()
    {
   echo  $this->getRequest()->getParam('template');
 }
```